# Regexp pattern Optional character

Tags: regex

I want to match a string like 19740103-0379 or 197401030379, i.e the dash is optional.
How do I accomplish this with regexp?

Comment: Specify the language and/or regex library you're using.

Comment: You could use [0-9]{8}-?[0-9]{4}

Answer (score 7):

Usually you can just use `-?`. Alternatively, you can use `-{0,1}` but you should find that `?` for "zero or one occurrences of" is supported just about everywhere.

```
pax> echo 19740103-0379 | egrep '19740103\-?0379'
19740103-0379

pax> echo 197401030379 | egrep '19740103\-?0379'
197401030379
```

If you want to accept 12 digits with any number of dashes in there anywhere, you might have to do something like:

```
-*([0-9]-*){12}
```

which is basically zero or more dashes followed by 12 occurrences of (a digit followed by zero or more dashes) and will capture all sorts of wonderful things like:

```
--3-53453---34-4534---
```

(of course, you should use `\d` instead of `[0-9]` if your regex engine has support for that).

Comment: You only need to escape `-` in a character class (`[...]`). A dash has no special meaning elsewhere in a regex.

Answer (score 1):

You could try different ones:

`\d*` matches a string consisting only of digits

`\d*-\d*` matches a string of format digits - dash - digits

`[0-9\-]*` matches a string consisting of only dashes and digits

You can combine them via `|` (or), so that you have for example `(\d*)|(\d*-\d*)`: matches formats just digits and digits-dash-digits.